# Reliable reference for David Hawkins’ "map of consciousness"

Tags: reference-request, consciousness

I've trying to find reference for these concepts in pop-culture: "map of consciousness", "power levels", and "level of consciousness".

Pop sources and Dr. Hawkins' book titled "Power v.s. Force" claim that Dr. Hawkins did multiple experiments measuring the "power scale" or "consciousness level" of subjects.

Examples of a reliable reference I am looking-for would be a published paper that contains precise definitions and/or replicable experimental procedures.

However, I find no paper on those concepts or related concepts. I wonder if the whole concepts are pseudo-science at all.  **Question:** are there any scientific sources for the measurement of "consciousness level" or "map of consciousness"?

Comment: Can you provide your own references to what you've read, and focus your post to a single question?

Comment: @BryanKrause Most of the sources are either from non-scientific media or Dr. Hawkins' own book. But I finally find one third-party source: https://www.spiritualteachers.org/david-hawkins/

Comment: I think it's a pretty good hint when people publish popular books without citing anything that they're not basing it on something citable; if they were, they'd cite it rather than just saying it like it's true and if they don't cite it they're plagiarizing. Beware the [fallacy fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_fallacy), of course, but otherwise I wouldn't spend too much time on this sort of writing.